# Using Red-Black-Trees in another Red-Black-Trees' nodes

Tags: java, nodes, red-black-tree

i'm stuck in a task which I could use a little help with. Basically, my job is to design a factory for wrapping presents. Our stocks are boxes with a square base (not necessarily cubes). For each box, we know the dimensions of the base of the box (I called it side) and the height (height). When the factory receives a request to wrap a present, the customer knows the side and height values of the smallest box that fits the present, but we will provide the box with the minimal volume that we have at the moment.

The idea is to plan a data structure to manage the boxes. The data structure has to support the following methods:

INSERTBOX(side, height) - adding a box to the data structure with the given dimensions

REMOVEBOX(side, height) - removing a box from the data structure with the given dimensions

GETBOX(side, height) - returning the dimensions of a box with minimal volume that fits for wrapping the present (of course, its dimension should be equal or larger than the given side and height...)

CHECKBOX(side,height) - checking whether there is a box in the storage that fits the present.

The parameters of the entire problem are the number of side values, m, and the number of height values, n.

I was thinking of a red-black tree that uses the side as the key, every node also holds a red-black tree in which all sides are equal and the height is now the key.

What I got stuck with is implenting the GetBox method, I just can't figure out a better way than checking every single node for the smallest volume in which the side and height are equal or larger than those who were entered by the user.

MAIN PROGRAM

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class ProgramBody
    {
        public static BoxesRedBlackTree sideTree = new BoxesRedBlackTree();
        public static void Main()
        {
            final int INSERTBOX = 1;
            final int REMOVEBOX = 2;
            final int GETBOX = 3;
            final int CHECKBOX = 4;
            final int EXIT = 5;

            System.out.println("Welcome to the factory! What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("Insert a box - " + INSERTBOX);
            System.out.println("Remove a box - " + REMOVEBOX);
            System.out.println("Get a box - " + GETBOX);
            System.out.println("Check if a box exists - " + CHECKBOX);
            System.out.println("Exit - " + EXIT);
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int Choise = in.nextInt();

            // While the user doesn't exit the program
            while (Choise != EXIT)
            {
                switch (Choise)
                {
                    case (INSERTBOX):
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the side");
                            int side = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the height");
                            int height = in.nextInt();

                            InsertBox(side, height);

                            break;
                        }
                    case (REMOVEBOX):
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the side");
                            int side = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the height");
                            int height = in.nextInt();

                            RemoveBox(side, height);

                            break;
                        }
                    case (GETBOX):
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the side");
                            int side = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the height");
                            int height = in.nextInt();

                            GetBox(side, height);

                            break;
                        }
                    case (CHECKBOX):
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the side");
                            int side = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the size of the height");
                            int height = in.nextInt();
                            boolean boxExists;

                            if (CheckBox(side, height))
                            { System.out.println("The box exists."); }
                            else
                            { System.out.println("The box doesn't exist."); }

                            break;
                        }
                        default:
                            { System.out.println("You have entered an unfamiliar choice. Please try again."); }
                    } 
                System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do now?");
                System.out.println("Insert a box - " + INSERTBOX);
                System.out.println("Remove a box - " + REMOVEBOX);
                System.out.println("Get a box - " + GETBOX);
                System.out.println("Check if a box exists - " + CHECKBOX);
                System.out.println("Exit - " + EXIT);
                System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");

                Choise = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        private static void InsertBox(int side, int height) {
            if (sideTree.sideExist(side))
            {
               //Check if There is same box
               if(sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().heightExist(height))
               { sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().searchByHeight(height).setCounter(sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().searchByHeight(height).getCounter()+1); }
               else
               { 
                BoxNode temp = new BoxNode(side, height, 1);
                sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().insert(temp);
               }

            }
            else 
            {
                BoxNode heightTempNode = new BoxNode(side, height, 1);
                BoxesRedBlackTree tempTree = new BoxesRedBlackTree();
                tempTree.insert(heightTempNode);
                BoxNode sideTempNode = new BoxNode(side, height, tempTree);
                sideTree.insert(sideTempNode);
            }
            System.out.println("The box with side " + side + " and height " + height + " has been added.");
        }
        private static void RemoveBox(int side, int height) {
            if(sideTree.sideExist(side) && sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().heightExist(height)) {
            if (sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().searchByHeight(height).getCounter() > 1)
            {
                sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().searchByHeight(height).setCounter(sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().searchByHeight(height).getCounter()-1);
                System.out.println("The box with side " + side + " and height " + height + " has been removed.");
            }
            else
            {
                sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().delete(sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().searchByHeight(height));
                System.out.println("The box with side " + side + " and height " + height + " has been removed.");
            }
            if (!sideTree.searchBySide(side).getTree().sideExist(side))
            {
                sideTree.delete(sideTree.searchBySide(side));
            } }
            else
            { System.out.println("There isn't a box with the requested size!"); }
        }
        private static BoxNode GetBox(int side, int height) { 
            BoxNode currentNode = sideTree.getMin(sideTree.getRoot());
            BoxNode minimalBox = sideTree.getRoot();
            // Check all The Tree
            while (currentNode != null)
                { if(currentNode.getSide() >= side && currentNode.getHeight() >= height && currentNode.getVolume() < minimalBox.getVolume()) { minimalBox = currentNode; }}
                    currentNode = sideTree.getSuccessor(currentNode);
            if (minimalBox != null)
                    { System.out.println("The box with side " + minimalBox.getSide() + " and height " + minimalBox.getSide() + " has returned."); }
                    else
                    { System.out.println("No box was found."); }
            return (minimalBox); 
        }
        private static boolean CheckBox(int side, int height) {
            if ((GetBox(side,height)) != null)
            { return true; }
            return false;  }
 }
```

RED BLACK TREE

```
public class BoxesRedBlackTree
{
    private BoxNode _root;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public BoxesRedBlackTree ()
    {
        _root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Reset root
     */
    public BoxesRedBlackTree(BoxNode box)
    {
        _root = new BoxNode(box);
    }

    /**
     * get -root method
     */
    public BoxNode getRoot()
    {
        return _root;
    }

    /**
     * LEFT-ROTATE algorithm
     */
    public void leftRotate(BoxNode x)
    { 
        BoxNode y = x.getRightSon();
        x.setRightSon(y.getLeftSon());
        if(y.getLeftSon() != null)
        {
            y.getLeftSon().setParent(x);
        }
        y.setParent(x.getParent());
        if(x.getParent() == null)
        {
            _root = y;
        }
        else if( x == x.getParent().getLeftSon())
        {
            x.getParent().setLeftSon(y);
        }
        else
        {
            x.getParent().setRightSon(y);
        }
        y.setLeftSon(x);
        x.setParent(y);
    }

    /**
     * RIGHT-ROTATE algorithm
     * Assumes right son of x is not null.
     */
    public void rightRotate(BoxNode x)
    { //assumes left son is not null
        BoxNode y = x.getLeftSon();
        x.setLeftSon(y.getRightSon());
        if(y.getRightSon() != null)
        {
            y.getRightSon().setParent(x);
        }
        y.setParent(x.getParent());
        if(x.getParent() == null)
        {
            _root = y;
        }
        else if( x == x.getParent().getRightSon())
        {
            x.getParent().setRightSon(y);
        }
        else
        {
            x.getParent().setLeftSon(y);
        }
        y.setRightSon(x);
        x.setParent(y);
    }

    /**
     * RB-INSERT algorithm
     */
    public void insert(BoxNode toInsert)
    { 
        BoxNode x = _root;
        BoxNode y = null;
        while(x != null){
            y = x;
            if(toInsert.isBigger(x))
            {
                x = x.getLeftSon();
            }
            else
            {
                x = x.getRightSon();
            }
        }
        toInsert.setParent(y);
        if(y == null)
        {
            _root = toInsert;
        }
        else if(toInsert.isBigger(y))
        {
            y.setLeftSon(toInsert);
        }
        else
        {
            y.setRightSon(toInsert);
        }

        toInsert.setLeftSon(null);
        toInsert.setRightSon(null);
        toInsert.setColor(1); // red
        insertFixUp(toInsert);

    }

    /**
     * RB-INSERT-FIXUP algorithm
     */
    private void insertFixUp(BoxNode z)
    {
        BoxNode y = null;
        while (z != _root && z.getParent().getColor() == 1)
        {
            if(z.getParent() == z.getParent().getParent().getLeftSon())
            {
                y = z.getParent().getParent().getRightSon();
                if(y != null && y.getColor()== 1)
                {
                    z.getParent().setColor(0);
                    y.setColor(0);
                    z = z.getParent().getParent();
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (z == z.getParent().getRightSon())
                    {
                        z = z.getParent();
                        this.leftRotate(z);
                    }
                    z.getParent().setColor(0);
                    z.getParent().getParent().setColor(1);
                    rightRotate(z.getParent().getParent());
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                y = z.getParent().getParent().getLeftSon();
                if(y != null && y.getColor() == 1)
                {
                    z.getParent().setColor(0);
                    y.setColor(0);
                    z = z.getParent().getParent();
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (z == z.getParent().getLeftSon()){
                        z = z.getParent();
                        this.rightRotate(z);
                    }
                    z.getParent().setColor(0);
                    z.getParent().getParent().setColor(1);
                    this.leftRotate(z.getParent().getParent());
                }
            }

        }
        _root.setColor(0);
    }

    /**
     * RB-DELETE algorithm
     */
    public void delete(BoxNode z)
    {
        BoxNode y = null;
        BoxNode x = null;
        if(z.getLeftSon() == null || z.getRightSon() == null)
        {
            y = z;
        }
        else
        {
            y = getSuccessor(z);
        }

        if(y.getLeftSon() != null)
        {
            x = y.getLeftSon();
        }
        else
        {
            x=y.getRightSon();
        }

        if (x != null && y != null)
        {
            x.setParent(y.getParent());
        }

        if(y.getParent() == null)
        {
            _root = x;
        }
        else if(y == y.getParent().getLeftSon())
        {
            y.getParent().setLeftSon(x);
        }
        else
        {
            y.getParent().setRightSon(x);
        }

        if(y != z)
        {
            z.setSide(y.getSide());
        }
        if(y.isBlack())
        {
            deleteFixUp(x);
        }
    }

    /**
     * RB-DELETE-FIXUP algorithm 
     */
    private void deleteFixUp(BoxNode x)
    {
        BoxNode temp = null;
        while (x != null && x != _root && x.isBlack())
        {
            if (x == x.getParent().getLeftSon())
            {
                temp = x.getParent().getRightSon();
                if (!temp.isBlack())
                {
                    temp.setColor(0); 
                    x.getParent().setColor(1);
                    leftRotate(x.getParent()); 
                    temp = x.getParent().getRightSon(); 
                }

                if (temp.getLeftSon().isBlack()  && temp.getRightSon().isBlack() )
                {
                    temp.setColor(1);
                    x = x.getParent(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    if (temp.getRightSon().isBlack())
                    {
                        temp.getLeftSon().setColor(0); 
                        temp.setColor(1); 
                        rightRotate (temp); 
                        temp = x.getParent().getRightSon(); 
                    }

                    temp.setColor(x.getParent().getColor()); 
                    x.getParent().setColor(0); 
                    temp.getRightSon().setColor(0); 
                    leftRotate (x.getParent()); 
                    x = _root; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp = x.getParent().getLeftSon();
                if (!temp.isBlack())
                {
                    temp.setColor(0); 
                    x.getParent().setColor(1); 
                    rightRotate(x.getParent()); 
                    temp = x.getParent().getLeftSon(); 
                }

                if (temp.getRightSon().isBlack() && temp.getLeftSon().isBlack())
                {
                    temp.setColor(1); 
                    x = x.getParent(); 
                }

                else 
                {
                    if (temp.getLeftSon().isBlack())
                    {
                        temp.getRightSon().setColor(0); 
                        temp.setColor(1); 
                        leftRotate (temp); 
                        temp = x.getParent().getLeftSon(); 
                    }

                    temp.setColor(x.getParent().getColor()); 
                    x.getParent().setColor(0); 
                    temp.getLeftSon().setColor(0); 
                    rightRotate (x.getParent()); 
                    x = _root; 
                }
            }
            x.setColor(0);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * returns the successor BoxNode of a certain BoxNodeFrom.
     */
    public BoxNode getSuccessor(BoxNode BoxNodeFrom)
    {
        if(BoxNodeFrom.getRightSon() != null)
        {
            return getMin(BoxNodeFrom.getRightSon());
        }
        BoxNode temp = BoxNodeFrom.getParent();
        while ((temp != null) && (BoxNodeFrom == temp.getRightSon()))
        {
            BoxNodeFrom = temp;
            temp = temp.getParent();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * Get the minimum Valued BoxNode from a given subtree
     */
    public BoxNode getMin(BoxNode BoxNodeFrom)
    {
        while (BoxNodeFrom.getLeftSon() != null)
        {
            BoxNodeFrom = BoxNodeFrom.getLeftSon();
        }
        return BoxNodeFrom;
    }

    /**
     * Get the maximum Valued BoxNode from a given subtree
     */
    public BoxNode getMax(BoxNode BoxNodeFrom)
    {
        while (BoxNodeFrom.getRightSon() != null)
        {
            BoxNodeFrom = BoxNodeFrom.getRightSon();
        }
        return BoxNodeFrom;
    }

    /**
     * search height in the Tree 
     * return the BoxNode Node if it exict, and NULL otherwise
     */
    public BoxNode searchByHeight(int boxCode)
    {
        BoxNode temp = _root;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (temp.getHeight() > boxCode)
            {
                temp = temp.getRightSon();
            }
            else if (temp.getHeight() < boxCode)
            {
                temp = temp.getLeftSon();
            }
            else
            {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * check if there is a height
     */
    public boolean heightExist(int height)
    {
        BoxNode temp = searchByHeight(height);
        if(temp == null)
        { return false; }
        return true;        
    }

     /**
     * search side in the Tree 
     * return the BoxNode Node if it exict, and NULL otherwise
     */
    public BoxNode searchBySide(int boxCode)
    {
        BoxNode temp = _root;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (temp.getSide() > boxCode)
            {
                temp = temp.getRightSon();
            }
            else if (temp.getSide() < boxCode)
            {
                temp = temp.getLeftSon();
            }
            else
            {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * check if there is a side
     */
    public boolean sideExist(int side)
    {
        BoxNode temp = searchBySide(side);
        if(temp == null)
        { return false; }
        return true;        
    }
}
```

NODE

```
public class BoxNode
{
    private int color=0; // black is 0 red is 1.
    private BoxNode rightSon, leftSon, parent; 

    private int _side;
    private int _height;
    private int _counter;
    private BoxesRedBlackTree _pointer;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public BoxNode(int side,int height)
    {
        _side = side;
        _height = height;
    }

    public BoxNode(int side,int height,int counter)
    {
        _side = side;
        _height = height;
        _counter = counter;
    }

    public BoxNode(int side,int height, BoxesRedBlackTree pointer)
    {
        _side = side;
        _height = height;
        _pointer = pointer;
    }

    /**
     * Copy Constructor
     */    
    public BoxNode(BoxNode box)
    {
        _side = box._side;
        _height = box._height;
    }

    //get Method

    /**
     * get the height of the node
     */        
    public int getHeight()
    { 
        return _height; 
    }

    /**
     * get the side of the box
     */        
    public int getSide()
    { 
        return _side; 
    }

    public int getCounter()
    { 
        return _counter; 
    }

    public BoxesRedBlackTree getTree()
    { 
        return _pointer; 
    }

    /**
     * get the volume of the box
     */        
    public int getVolume()
    { 
        return (_side)*(_side)*(_height); 
    }

     public BoxNode getRightSon()
    {
        return rightSon;
    }

    public BoxNode getLeftSon()
    {
        return leftSon;
    }

    public BoxNode getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }
    public int getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    //set Method

    /**
     * set the side
     */    
    public void setSide(int side)
    { 
        _side = side; 
    }

    /**
     * set the height
     */    
    public void setHeight(int height)
    { 
        _height = height; 
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter)
    { 
        _counter = counter; 
    }

    public void setTree(BoxesRedBlackTree pointer)
    { 
        _pointer = pointer; 
    }

    public void setRightSon(BoxNode toSet)
    {
        rightSon = toSet;
    }

    public void setLeftSon(BoxNode toSet)
    {
        leftSon = toSet;
    }

    public void setParent(BoxNode toSet )
    {
        parent = toSet;
    }

    public void setColor(int toSet)
    {
        if(toSet == 1 || toSet == 0)
        {
            color = toSet;
        }
    }


    public boolean isBigger(BoxNode other)
    {
        if(_side > other._side)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isBlack()
    { return true; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the volume of the box as the key? In your getBox method, you can get the box with the smallest volume that is greater than or equal to side^2*height. Then, check if it can fit the given side and height. If not, try the next bigger one. This can perform decently, depending on the sizes of your boxes and presents.

If you're really bent on nested red-black trees, you can do th following:
1) Find the sideNode with the minimum side that's greater than or equal to the given side.
2) Find the heightNode with the minimum height that's greater than or equal to the given height. Hold it in a variable named minVolumeBox.
3) Get the next sideNode. Keep doing this until 
  a) You check all the available sideNodes or
  b) The side of the sideNode is bigger than (volume of minVolumeBox / given height).

Case 3b will save you some time over checking every single node.